# "Object is possibly 'null' ", " Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CloudProduct'" , +.... in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, bootstrap-5

So, I made my backend API, I can create products, update them and/or delete them, and I was asked to make its frontend now.
I'm supposed to use Angular, and i'm aswell using bootstrap.
I could make the homepage look nice, but without anything being responsive, such as my add, edit or delete buttons.
I'm following a guide to how to make a pop-up form using Angular Modal with Bootstrap.
I'm getting these errors when trying to ng serve :

```
Warning: src/app/app.component.html:74:94 - warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.

74            <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateProductModalLabel">Edit Product{{editProduct?.productName}}</h5>
                                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Warning: src/app/app.component.html:83:61 - warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.

83                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editProduct?.productName}}" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Warning: src/app/app.component.html:85:60 - warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.

85               <input type="hidden" ngModel="{{editProduct?.productId}}" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Email">
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Warning: src/app/app.component.html:88:69 - warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.

88                  <input type="priceInEuros" ngModel="{{editProduct?.priceInEuros}}" name="priceInEuros" class="form-control" id="priceInEuros" placeholder="Email">
                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Warning: src/app/app.component.html:111:73 - warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.

111            <p>Are you sure you want to delete Product{{deleteProduct?.productName}}?</p>
                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Warning: src/app/app.component.html:114:63 - warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.

114               <button (click)="onDeleteProduct(deleteProduct?.productId)" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.




Error: src/app/app.component.html:11:50 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CloudProduct'.

11         <a class="nav-link" (click)="onOpenModal(null, 'add')">Add product <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                                    ~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:114:48 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

114               <button (click)="onDeleteProduct(deleteProduct?.productId)" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.ts:35:5 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

35     document.getElementById('add-product-form').click();
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~




× Failed to compile.
```

my app.component.html:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;">Products Manager</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="onOpenModal(null, 'add')">Add product <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
     </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" id="main-container">
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let cloudProduct of cloudProducts" class="col-md-3">
        <div class="ibox">
            <div class="ibox-content product-box">
                <div class="product-desc">
                    <a class="product-name"> {{cloudProduct?.productName}}</a>

                    <div class="small m-t-xs">
                        Created At : {{cloudProduct?.createdAt}}
                    </div>
                    <span class="product-price">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-times"> </i></button>
                  </span>
                    <div class="m-ttext-righ">
                      {{cloudProduct?.priceInEuros}}€
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="addProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addProductModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="addProductModalLabel">Add Product</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddProduct(addForm)">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="productName">Name</label>
             <input type="text" ngModel name="productName" class="form-control" id="productName" placeholder="productName" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="priceInEuros">Price</label>
             <input type="number" ngModel name="priceInEuros" class="form-control" id="priceInEuros" placeholder="priceInEuros" required>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" id="add-product-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             <button [disabled]="addForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
          </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- Edit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="updateProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateProductModalLabel">Edit Product{{editProduct?.productName}}</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <form #editForm="ngForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="name">Name</label>
                 <input type="text" ngModel="{{editProduct?.productName}}" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" ngModel="{{editProduct?.productId}}" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Email">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="priceInEuros">Price</label>
                 <input type="priceInEuros" ngModel="{{editProduct?.priceInEuros}}" name="priceInEuros" class="form-control" id="priceInEuros" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                 <button (click)="onUpdateProduct(editForm.value)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
              </div>
           </form>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Delete Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModelLabel">Delete Product</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <p>Are you sure you want to delete product {{deleteProduct?.productName}}?</p>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
              <button (click)="onDeleteProduct(deleteProduct?.productId)" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my app.component.ts :

```
import { CloudProductService } from './cloudproduct.service';
import { CloudProduct } from './cloudproduct';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public cloudProducts: CloudProduct[];
  public editProduct: CloudProduct;
  public deleteProduct: CloudProduct;
  constructor(private cloudProductService: CloudProductService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getCloudProducts();
  }

    public getCloudProducts():void{
      this.cloudProductService.getCloudProducts().subscribe(
        (response: CloudProduct[]) =>{
          this.cloudProducts = response;
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          alert(error.message);
        }
      );
  }

  public onAddProduct(addForm: NgForm): void {
    document.getElementById('add-product-form').click();
    this.cloudProductService.createCloudProduct(addForm.value).subscribe(
      (response: CloudProduct) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getCloudProducts();
        addForm.reset();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
        addForm.reset();
      }
    );
  }

  public onUpdateProduct(cloudProduct: CloudProduct): void {
    this.cloudProductService.updateCloudProduct(cloudProduct).subscribe(
      (response: CloudProduct) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getCloudProducts();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  public onDeleteProduct(productId:number): void {
    this.cloudProductService.deleteCloudProduct(productId).subscribe(
      (response: void) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getCloudProducts();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }


  public onOpenModal(cloudProduct: CloudProduct, mode: string): void {
    const container = document.getElementById('main-container');
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.style.display = 'none';
    button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
    if (mode === 'add') {
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#addProductModal');
    }
    if (mode === 'edit') {
      this.editProduct = cloudProduct;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#updateProductModal');
    }
    if (mode === 'delete') {
      this.deleteProduct = cloudProduct;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#deleteProductModal');
    }
    container!.appendChild(button);
    button.click();
  }


}
```

I tried to find solutions for them, but without any success !!
How can I solve them ?

Tell me if you need anything else !!

Comment: Did you read the error and try to do what it suggests?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using **optional chaining** for variables that cant be null or undefined as far as the compiler knows.

on your app.component.ts you have:

```
public editProduct: CloudProduct;
public deleteProduct: CloudProduct;
```

Here you are saying that the editProduct and deleteProduct variables **contain and will always contain CloudProduct objects**. So, when you do:

```
editProduct?.productName
deleteProduct?.productName
```

You are saying "bring me the productName if this variable is not null or undefined", but you already said that those variable can only be CloudProduct objects.

To solve the issue I can think of 2 approaches.

The first one is to declare your variables as follows:

```
 public editProduct: CloudProduct | undefined;
 public deleteProduct: CloudProduct | undefined;
```

This tells the compiler those variables could be undefined and your template should attempt to read its values only if they are not undefined.

The second one is to stop using the optional chaining operator for those variables and ensure that the values are there when they are needed.

More info on the optional chaining operator here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: Okay Sir, it worked, for the warning, but what about the errors ? Specially this one " Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CloudProduct' "

Comment: You are passing "null" to the *openModal* function on its first parameter but it should be a CloudProduct object. Which btw is not used inside the function so you probably can get rid of that argument and edit all calls to that function.

Comment: Managed to fix that, made my cloudproduct undefined aswell, the only error I'm getting now is that "Object is possibly 'null'." in my "document.getElementById('add-product-form').click();"

Comment: Now, typescript can't tell if there really is an element with the id 'add-product-form', so it's letting you know that it is possible it cant find an element with such id, in this case, you can use the **non-null assertion operator (!)* or the *optional chaining operator*. Using optional chaining will never try to call "click()" on your element if it isn't defined so you will not receive an error at runtime if the element is null. Using non-null assertion will throw an error on the browser if you try to call click() but there was no element with the id 'add-product-form'.

Edit: typo

Comment: Okay Sir, now it is all solved, I tried the add product feature, when I hit the submit, it does create the product that was supposed, but it gives this message " Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/cloudproduct/add", but, I repeat, it creates successfully

Comment: In fact, everything solved besides the """Argument of type 'number | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.""" on my deleteModal, but since I'm not getting it fixed I'm just commentating it.